# How to assemble and pass a variable to a filter

Tags: r, variables, filter

In my work, I need to parse a string and pass it as a filter to a function so I can calculate some statistics. Using mpg dataset as a example, instead of doing

```
mpg |> filter(manufacturer %in% c("ford","honda","hyundai","jeep"))
```

What I have is a string that represents the manufacturers I want

```
manufacturer_list <- "ford,honda,hyundai,jeep"
```

I need to convert this list to a format that can recognized by filter function so that I can do

```
mpg |> filter(manufacturer %in% c(manufacturer_filter_value))
```

I can use `str_extract` and then `paste0` to assemble the list to a quoted and comma separated string, but it's not recognized as a proper filter value and I got 0 record back

Answer (score 2):

You need to split this single string into a character vector before passing it to `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

manufacturer_list <- "ford,honda,hyundai,jeep"
mpg |> filter(manufacturer %in% unlist(strsplit(manufacturer_list, ',')))

# A tibble: 56 × 11
#   manufacturer model           displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class 
#   <chr>        <chr>           <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
# 1 ford         expedition 2wd    4.6  1999     8 auto(l4)   r        11    17 r     suv   
# 2 ford         expedition 2wd    5.4  1999     8 auto(l4)   r        11    17 r     suv   
# 3 ford         expedition 2wd    5.4  2008     8 auto(l6)   r        12    18 r     suv   
# 4 ford         explorer 4wd      4    1999     6 auto(l5)   4        14    17 r     suv   
# 5 ford         explorer 4wd      4    1999     6 manual(m5) 4        15    19 r     suv   
# 6 ford         explorer 4wd      4    1999     6 auto(l5)   4        14    17 r     suv   
# 7 ford         explorer 4wd      4    2008     6 auto(l5)   4        13    19 r     suv   
# 8 ford         explorer 4wd      4.6  2008     8 auto(l6)   4        13    19 r     suv   
# 9 ford         explorer 4wd      5    1999     8 auto(l4)   4        13    17 r     suv   
#10 ford         f150 pickup 4wd   4.2  1999     6 auto(l4)   4        14    17 r     pickup
# ℹ 46 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

where `strsplit` with `unlist` would return

```
unlist(strsplit(manufacturer_list, ','))
#[1] "ford"    "honda"   "hyundai" "jeep"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but works also using `scan`:

```
library(dplyr)

manufacturer_list <- "ford,honda,hyundai,jeep"
mpg |> 
  filter(manufacturer %in% scan(text = manufacturer_list, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))
```

```
 A tibble: 56 × 11
   manufacturer model          displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class
   <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
 1 ford         expedition 2wd   4.6  1999     8 auto… r        11    17 r     suv  
 2 ford         expedition 2wd   5.4  1999     8 auto… r        11    17 r     suv  
 3 ford         expedition 2wd   5.4  2008     8 auto… r        12    18 r     suv  
 4 ford         explorer 4wd     4    1999     6 auto… 4        14    17 r     suv  
 5 ford         explorer 4wd     4    1999     6 manu… 4        15    19 r     suv  
 6 ford         explorer 4wd     4    1999     6 auto… 4        14    17 r     suv  
 7 ford         explorer 4wd     4    2008     6 auto… 4        13    19 r     suv  
 8 ford         explorer 4wd     4.6  2008     8 auto… 4        13    19 r     suv  
 9 ford         explorer 4wd     5    1999     8 auto… 4        13    17 r     suv  
10 ford         f150 pickup 4…   4.2  1999     6 auto… 4        14    17 r     pick…
# ℹ 46 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```